# What happens behind the scenes when the following line is running\compiling in java: (LinkedList<Dog>)(Object)(new LinkedList<Car>());?

Tags: java, generics, casting, compilation, runtime

When writing:

```
LinkedList<Dog> dogList = (LinkedList<Dog>)(Object)(new LinkedList<Car>());
```

I get no ClassCastException, as opposed to just writing:

```
Dog dog = (Dog)(Object)(new Car());
```

Why is there a difference? (what happens behind the scenes?)

I assume it has something to do with java's generics mechanism.

Comment: I just noticed that the question in your title is different from the question in your text. Which one did you mean to ask? Please edit your question to clarify.